# Creating separate shapefiles for each attribute record using loop in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, loop

Line 24 fixed, final code now updated.
Line 22 since fixed , now I get the error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shehn\Documents\ArcGIS\PyScripts\lab6X.py", line 24, in 
    arcpy.Select_analysis (inputFile, outSHP, "\"FID\" = '" + each_attribute + "'")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

---

Here is what I tried to do when I looked at the existing way , I got the error : Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\shehn\Documents\ArcGIS\PyScripts\lab6X.py", line 22, in 
    outSHP = outDir + each_attribute + u".shp"
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

> > > 

```
import arcpy

#Set OverWrite if files already exist
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set Input Output variables
inputFile = u"C:\\Users\shehn\\Documents\\2018\\LD ARCH 221\\lab 5\\burn2.shp"
outDir = u"C:\\Users\\shehn\\Documents\\2018\\LD ARCH 221\\lab 5" 

# Reads My_shapefile for different values in the attribute
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inputFile)
row = rows.next()
attribute_types = set([])

while row:
    attribute_types.add(row.FID)
    row = rows.next()

# Output a Shapefile for each different attribute
for each_attribute in attribute_types:
    outSHP = outDir + each_attribute + u".shp"
    print outSHP
    arcpy.Select_analysis (inputFile, outSHP, "FID = {0}".format(each_attribute)) 

del rows, row, attribute_types
```

I have to do this in ArcPy, otherwise I would have made a model in Model Builder. I am very new to Python. I think most of my code works, it seems to have an error at the CopyFeatures section. I am trying to get all 20 record in the FID column to become separate shapefiles so I have multiple polygons instead of one. I have tried the solution here "Exporting feature class into multiple feature classes based on field values using ArcGIS Desktop?" but it keeps giving me the expected string but got int error, so I tried doing it this way.

Here is my code:

```
# import system modules
import arcpy

# set workspace environment
env = arcpy.env.workspace = u"C:\\Users\shehn\\Documents\\2018\\LD ARCH 221\\lab 5\\burn2.shp"

#Set OverWrite if files already exist
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Make a layer from the feature class
FC = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("burn2.shp", "FC")

#Create a list of years to iterate through to enable selection of each year
FIDlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
print FIDlist

#Initiate Search Cursor to use in loop of attribute values
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(FC)

for row in rows:

    fieldName = "FID"
    value = row.getValue(fieldName)
    for field in FIDlist:
        Year_layer = str(field) + "_"  

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC, Year_layer)  

        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (Year_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"FID\" = %s" % (field))  

        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Year_layer, "fc_" + str(field))
```

Comment: I hate seeing the MakeFeatureLayer/SelectByAttribute/CopyFeatures coding pattern when Select_analysis() is so much easier -  see https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/68018/115 for an example.  Also, I see no need to use a SearchCursor here, and if you do, then use arcpy.da.SearchCursor() rather than the old arcpy.SearchCursor().

Comment: From the duplicate this is the answer that seems closest to the way that you are trying to do it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152165/115

Comment: If you find anything that "seems to have an error" it is always best to include the full error message including line number.

Comment: @PolyGeo, apologies, I'll add that now.

Comment: Try `outSHP = outDir + str(each_attribute) + u".shp"`

Comment: @PolyGeo that seems to have fixed that line, but then I get the error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shehn\Documents\ArcGIS\PyScripts\lab6X.py", line 24, in <module>
    arcpy.Select_analysis (inputFile, outSHP, "\"FID\" = '" + each_attribute + "'")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Try `arcpy.Select_analysis (inputFile, outSHP, "FID = {0}".format(each_attribute)) `

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you so much! I added an overwrite function and the script works perfectly!